# Infinite Scroll

Tags: ajax, infinite-scroll

I am trying to add infinite scroll functionality into my Wordpress theme.

I started my exploration of infinite scroll in Wordpress by going [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/infinite-scroll/infinity.php).

My question is, I don't understand the codex code, and I also don't understand why it appears that Jetpack's infinite scroll circumvents [`//calling admin-ajax`](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/infinite-scroll/infinity.php#L679) as explained in their source code.

In Jetpack's implementation, I don't see any `wp_ajax_nopriv()` calls.

I also really don't understand why I could check `if_admin()` if the point is that the `nopriv()` runs for unauthenticated users.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_frontend_action', 'my_frontend_action_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_frontend_action', 'my_frontend_action_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_backend_action', 'my_backend_action_callback' );
    // Add other back-end action hooks here
} else {
    // Add non-Ajax front-end action hooks here
}
```

I've employed infinite scroll in a custom PHP application before, and it was very easy, but this is currently lost on me.

I simply want to understand how to generate an ajax url to the backend to connect to a function that will handle the output for me, by returning data to the view. How do I go about doing that for unauthenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

`is_admin()` runs when you are logged in as admin in the backend. So you need to do `!is_admin()` to run for normal users.